# $\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty{\frac1{mn}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've surfed almost half of the Internet [:-)] but didn't succeed in finding an answers:

1) Does the series in the title have a special name?

2) Does it converge or diverge? Proof appreciated

3a) If it converges what is it value?

3b) If it diverges does there exist such $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that $\sum_{a_1,a_2,...,a_n=1}^\infty\frac1{a_1a_2...a_n}$ converges?

Comment: You may notice that $$\sum_{m,n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{mn}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^{N}\frac{1}{m} = H_N^2,$$ hence the outcome is pretty obvious.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Then diverges twice! :)

Comment: So... it diverges and there does not exist such $n$ that series in 3b converges, does it?

Comment: And what about special name?

Comment: @MikalaiParshutsich The partial sums are the [Squares of the harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: This reminds me of the sum:  $\sum_{(m,n)=1} \frac{1}{mn}$ which has a nice closed form.

Comment: @Mustafa Said. And how does this closed form look like?))

Comment: @MikalaiParshutsichs I think its $\zeta(2)^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to the comment by Jack D'Aurizio,  to show the divergence we can simply observe that

$$\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty{\frac1{mn}}\ge \sum_{\substack{n=1}\\(m=1)}^\infty{\frac1{1\cdot n}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac1{n}}$$

and we can generalize of course

$$\sum_{a_1,a_2,...,a_n=1}^\infty\frac1{a_1a_2...a_n}\ge \sum_{\substack{a_1=1}\\(a_2,\ldots a_n=1)}^\infty{\frac1{1\cdot a_1}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac1{n}}$$

Comment: @egreg Please, how can I fix the multiple line under the sum? Thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm just having a brain fart, or perhaps I'm just really tired, but why can we say that $$\sum_{m,n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{mn} \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$$ It seems to me that $\frac{1}{mn} \leq \frac{1}{n}$ for every $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @user516079 If we fix $m=1$ we are neglecting all the positive terms for $m=2,3,...$

Comment: Oh I see I see! Thank you.